# OpenCL on Mobile Intel(R) 965 Express Chipset Family

Tags: opencl, gpu, intel

I have a Mobile Intel(R) 965 Express Chipset Family as my graphics card on my Dell Inspiron.

I wanted to run OpenCL programs on the GPU using this. Does this graphics card support that? I read a lot online but I still haven't come to a conclusion.

If not, is there an alternative solution apart from changing my computer?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to run OpenCL on the GPU in the 965 chipset.  There's a hardware support matrix for Intel's SDK for OpenCL applications here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-sdk-frequently-asked-questions.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for more information on their OpenCL legacy device support in 2022 it pretty much stands as:

- 1st/2nd Gen Core i = CPU Only.
- 3rd/4th Gen = CPU + Limited Beignet GPU OpenCL support + Intel OpenCL proprietary deprecated support
- 5th and 6th Gen Core = mostly supported
- 7th Gen + supported

7th Gen meaning i3/5/7 7000 series, Kaby Lake.